# Drupal 6: login problems in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, drupal-6

What may cause the problem with user login in Internet Explorer?
When I try to log in Drupal just shows the message `You don't have permission to view ..... Please login`.

By the way on Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera there is no such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution drupal 6 maybe here http://drupal.org/node/1043154  Check out.